# CM 12.1 Nightly Mako Home Button Not Showing

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-4, bugs

When I go to landscape mode on my Nexus 4 with a CM 12.1 Nightly, the home button gets cut off, and the other buttons are not showing. How can I fix this?

Comment: Give us the screenshots of both portrait and landscape mode. Which nightly build are you using? Is it official or unofficial?

Comment: It is an official nightly build, and updating it doesn't change it

Comment: Screenshots are still required though.

Answer (score -1):

This is a system ui issue.
A simple restart will definitely fix this problem.
If it doesn't, make sure to do a clean reflash again.

Comment: This doesn't work at all.